# How to resize font-size proportionally to div size

Tags: javascript, css, html, text, autoresize

I'm trying to create a website where the pages resize to the windows size on the fly. While we can get images and such to resize automatically as a % of the div size. We do not seem to be able to resize the text within a div to a relative % of the container.

This feature would need to work as the browser window itself is resized, without having to refresh the page.

The site is basic and is using js,css, html. The simplest method possible would be appreciated, but any solution is fantastic.

Thanks

Comment: can you please post your code so I can try to get this working for you?

Answer (score 2):

Whipped up some example to adjust font-size on div size change. Using percentage in the parent div and adjusting the font-size there should do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/744A2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#bigger').click(function() {
    $('#test').css('height', $('#test').height() + 100 + 'px');
    $('#test').css('width', $('#test').width() + 100 + 'px');
    check_resize();
  });
  $('#smaller').click(function() {
    $('#test').css('height', $('#test').height() - 100 + 'px');
    $('#test').css('width', $('#test').width() - 100 + 'px');
    check_resize();
  });

});

function check_resize() {
  var h = 50;
  var w = 200;

  var width = $('#test').width();
  var perc = percentage(width, w);

  $('#test').css('font-size', perc + '%');
}

function percentage(a, b) {
  return a / b * 100;
}
```

```css
#test {
  font-size: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}

#test h1,
#test p {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
<input type="button" value="smaller" id="smaller" />
<input type="button" value="bigger" id="bigger" />
```

Answer (score 2):

So you can use screen.availHeight to calculate a constant value which you can multiply with the font size.

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.body.style.fontSize = (Math.ceil(screen.availHeight * parseInt(document.body.style.fontSize) / 600) + 'px';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using media queries?

Answer (score 0):

even use % for text.
http://w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

Comment: unfortunately that does not work because with font-size it sets it as "Sets the font-size to a percent of  the parent element's font size". I need it to be a % of the parent element itself.

But i appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: if you are using %age for div width. then it automatically adjusts the text also.